# Javascript moving element to mouse click position, element not responding

Tags: javascript, animation, onclick

I'm trying to get my png to move to the mouse click position when the user clicks within the container but I cant get the png to respond. I'm following this tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b4GwvdhrEQg), and stuck on the first test. my target doesnt respond to clicks at all.
Please help

```js
var theGirl = document.querySelector("#girl");

var container = document.querySelector("#floor");

container.addEventListener("click", getClickPosition, false);

function getClickPosition(e) {
  var xPosition = e.clientX - (theGirl.offsetWidth / 2);
  var yPosition = e.clientY; - (theGirl.offsetHeight / 2)
  var translate3dValue = "translate3d(" + xPosition + "px" + yPosition + "px, 0)";
  theGirl.style.transform = translate3dValue;
}
```

```css
#floor {
  width: 700px;
  height: 600px;
  cursor: pointer;
  overflow: visible;
  border: 10px #EDEDED solid;
}

#girl {
  height: 450px;
  width: 200px;
  border: 15px red solid;
  transform: translate3d(50px, 50px, 0);
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="floor">
    <div>
      <img src="girl.png" id="girl"> </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Try logging `translate3dValue` and I think you'll see the problem immediately.

Comment: You're missing a comma between the X and Y positions.

Comment: @BARMAR THANK YOU SO MUCH OMG IVE BEEN STRUGGLING FOR LIKE 2 HOURS AND THAT IMMEDIATELY FIXED IT YOU'RE THE BEST THANK YOU SO MUCH

Answer (score 0):

Change #girl's position to absolute. I think it works after that.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).